# Bcrypt hashing not supported, Mcrypt installed

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, php-5.3, mcrypt

Trying to hash a password in laravel four using `Hash::make('password');` and get the error `Bcrypt hashing not supported.` in return.

Mcrypt is installed and phpinfo() confirms this, what else could be wrong?

Debian 6.0 X64 with PHP 5.3.3-7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Laravel requirements](http://laravel.com/docs/installation) are PHP >=5.3.7

You said you are running 5.3.3-7 - which is less than 5.3.7

Can you upgrade your PHP version?

Answer (score 3):

As The Shift Exchange said, 5.3.7 is the minimum for a 'vanilla' Laravel 4, but there is at least one option, if you really cannot upgrade your PHP server. This one will drop the minimum PHP version for Laravel 4 to 5.3.2:

https://github.com/robclancy/laravel4-hashing

Before using it, weigh your security needs, because it will also drop the security level of your hashes.